# Show as empty for Duplicates in Particular column in MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, select, subquery

I am having a table called Bills in MySQL.

```
Bill         item          totalprice

BILL_1       Fossil Watch  9000
BILL_1       Fastrack      9000
BILL_1       Fastrack      9000
BILL_2       Woodlands     7000
BILL_2       Woodlands     7000
BILL_3       Denim Shirt   9000
BILL_3       Levis Jean    9000
```

The SELECT statement should return like below

```
Bill         item          totalprice

BILL_1       Fossil Watch  9000
BILL_1       Fastrack      -
BILL_1       Fastrack      -
BILL_2       Woodlands     7000
BILL_2       Woodlands     -
BILL_3       Denim Shirt   9000
BILL_3       Levis Jean    -
The totalprice column is total bill amount.
```

Comment: is `Bill` a primary key column?

Comment: Is there any kind of id column or other column which could be used for ordering the transactions?

Comment: Hi @Grace it is not a primary column

Comment: @Viki Cullen: does  the five records means they are within the same bill?

Comment: Sorry, i have updated the table now @Grace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you exactly want or not, but try it:

```
select t.Bill, t.item, t.totalPrice
from (
    select 
        b.Bill, b.item
        ,if(@price <> b.totalPrice or @price is null, b.totalPrice, '-') as totalPrice
        ,@price := b.totalPrice as dummy
    from (select * from Bills order by totalPrice desc, item desc) b
    cross join (select @price := null) t
) t
```

<kbd>[Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c34f/4)</kbd>

***Edited:***

```
select t.Bill, t.item, t.totalPrice
from (
    select 
        b.Bill, b.item
        ,if(@price <> b.totalPrice or @price is null, b.totalPrice, '-') as totalPrice
        ,@price := b.totalPrice as dummy
    from (select * from Bills order by Bill, totalPrice desc) b
    cross join (select @price := null) t
) t
```

[<kbd>New Demo</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b10254/1)

Comment: I have edited my question now , the result should correspond against the column Bill